# how to use input in a span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem with some functions. I am new with JQuery and I would like to know how I could solve this problem that does not work for me. In the script part I have:

```js
$("#restar").click(function() {
  $.post("performsr.php", {
      u: $("#user").val(),
      a: 1
    })
    .done(function(data) {
       if(data == "1"){ location.reload(); } });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="restar">
<input type="hidden" id="user" value="Nick Name" /> - 
</span>
```

Comment: What are you expecting the code to do? Please explain the problem with more details.

Comment: I don't run the php as I want

Comment: What do you expect the PHP to do exactly? What isn't working?

Comment: The php performs the function well. The function of the script would be:
$( "#restar" ).click(function() {
   $.post( "realizarsr.php", { u: $("#user").val(), a: 1 })
   .done(function( data ) {
    if(data == "1"){
     location.reload();
    }
   });
  });

But it does not perform any action

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a bit too vague at this point. It's not clear what specifically is not working. You have not presented a "problem" nor have you made it clear what should happen when it's working correctly, so no goal. Please review: How do I ask a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It would also be good to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this. The problem is that the php (performr) should perform a function. When performing this function, if you give as data "1" you would have to reload and subtract a data (try the php performsr and it works correctly). The problem I have is in the script or in the span-input but I can't repair it

Comment: as your console shows, there is a syntax error in your function. Kindly remove the last line and try again.. '})'; use some good editor to identify the open and close braces.

Comment: Hi, I just checked and my code is fine, it is:
$ ("#restar") .click (function () {
$ .post ("performsr.php", {u: $ ("# user"). val (), to: 1})
.done (function (data) {
if (data == "1") {
location.reload ();
}
});
});

I took him away as he told me and it doesn't work. It only works in the first row of my table